# how to create a dataflow in azure sdk python

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-python

How can I establish a connection between a source and sink in a dataflow using Azure SDK in Python? I'm encountering difficulties when attempting to create the link between the two components. Could someone please help identify the issue?

Additionally, could you please provide a code example that demonstrates how to create a dataflow using Azure SDK in Python?

Comment: Refer the github issues I raised to resolve your query - 1) https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/110147 I tried deploying Azure ADF pipeline by referring the code in this Ms Document- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-python but the sample gave errors and this sample is related to copy activity the source and sink dataset was created successfully but did not get linked to Linked  service  2) I raised another github issue to get the working sample code for dataflow activity- https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/issues/579